# iPod Apps to record sound

Tags: portable-recorder

Hello all,

I've been needing a portable sound recorder for a while now but due to personal circumstance I don't have the money to buy one (and the mics etc). IK multimedia have seemingly come to save me by releasing the [iRig](http://www.ikmultimedia.com/irig/features/) which means I can use my iPod Touch as a recorder.

Before I buy one I've bodged together some cables to do the same job of mono in and stereo out.

I want to know if anyone has used and can recommend an App for sound recording.

I've had a quick scan on iTunes and one that stood out was [VC Audio Pro](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/vc-audio-pro/id354608007?mt=8) or [microDAW](http://itunes.apple.com/ie/app/microdaw/id374190097?mt=8).

I know it wont touch a decent unit and I could always borrow the DAT from work but it's a cumbersome thing that is rarely in the building for any length of time. I just want something to put in my manbag to grab things when they appear randomly.

Ian

Answer (score 4):

Coincidence!  I've just finished a post about recording with the iPhone on my blog (where there are links to some iPhone recordings).

http://sonicskepsi.wordpress.com/2010/06/16/audioboo-and-iphone-recordings/

Seems like you've done better than me in terms of discovering audio apps:  VC Audio Pro looks pretty cool in terms of editing functions, reckon I'll get that.  I've gone for FiRe and McDSP's Retro Recorder so far (no editing functions on these).....BUT, thought I'd check you knew about the Blue Microphones Mikey mic that you plug in to your iPhone / iPod which is supposed to improve things a lot.

http://www.bluemic.com/mikey/new/

A new version is being released soon (may already be released in States) - only about £60.  I too have been planning on getting a small portable recorder for my bag but at 200 to 300 quid for basic ones which don't sound great, I've decided to hold out for this Mikey and see how it sounds.  Plus I will never have any portable recorder on me as much as I have my iPhone with me!

Comment: Good stuff Michael. I liked the results you got. Might just have to get Fire. Although being a member of the last generation that used tape I might just have to get the Retro Recorder too.

Comment: If Retro Recorder was truly authentic you'd have to blow on your phone and tap it to stop it going wobbly......(or was it just me that did that with cassettes?)

Answer (score 3):

Audiofile Engineering's [FiRe](http://itunes.apple.com/app/fire-field-recorder/id309378684?mt=8)? (itunes link and i haven't tested it)